# What API to get or evaluate the global variables defined in MSBuild.exe.config?

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-api

I'm writing an application to evaluate (but not build) *.csproj and other project files.

The application emulates what MSBuild does. It uses the (documented) public APIs exposed by the `Microsoft.Build.dll` instances, which are installed in Visual Studio folders for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\
```

In those directories there's an `MSBuild.exe.config` file which contains an `msbuildToolsets` section like this:

```
<msbuildToolsets default="Current">
  <toolset toolsVersion="Current">
    <property name="MSBuildToolsPath" value="$([MSBuild]::GetCurrentToolsDirectory())" />
    <property name="MSBuildToolsPath32" value="$([MSBuild]::GetToolsDirectory32())" />
    <property name="MSBuildToolsPath64" value="$([MSBuild]::GetToolsDirectory64())" />
    <property name="MSBuildSDKsPath" value="$([MSBuild]::GetMSBuildSDKsPath())" />
    <property name="FrameworkSDKRoot" value="$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.8@InstallationFolder)" />
    <property name="MSBuildRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.30319" />
    <property name="MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath" value="$(SystemRoot)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v$(MSBuildRuntimeVersion)\" />
    ... etc ...
```

These entries define the values of global variables which are set when the *.csproj are evaluated.

In [the dotnet/msbuild source code](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) I see that:

- A function like `GetMSBuildSDKsPath()` is defined in the `IntrinsicFunctions` class (in the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` namespace), which is an `internal static` class.
- The implementation of this function delegates to `BuildEnvironmentHelper` (in the `Microsoft.Build.Shared` namespace), which is also an `internal` class.

It's crucial that these global variables be set correctly when invoking MSBuild, for example when calling the `ProjectCollection.LoadProject` method to return a `Project` instance (otherwise the project won't load).

An API to set these variables is to pass them via the `globalProperties` parameter to the `ProjectCollection` -- but I don't know how to get or evaluate the values of these properties, which I should set.

My question is -- **how can I read these variables** (given that the classes listed above are 'internal`)? Is there a public API that will do this?

If necessary I can run my application in the MSBuild bin folder, and/or copy the `MSBuild.exe.config` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to use:

- Set the `MSBUILD_EXE_PATH` environment variable
- Instantiate a `BuildParameters`
- Call its `GetToolset` method
- The parameters are in the `Properties` of the toolset

The directory paths (e.g. `Enterprise`) may vary from machine to machine.
To be more robust you could implement a run-time probe to discover it instead of hard-coding it.

```
        private readonly string _toolsPath;
        private readonly string _toolsVersion;

        public EvaluateCondition(string solutionPath)
        {
            var toolsets = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"2.0", @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727"},
                {"3.5", @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5"},
                {"4.0", @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319"},
                {"15.0", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"},
                {"Current" /*"16.0"*/, @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"}
            };

            // specify which version of the toolset we want to use
            // this is a compile-time definition but could have been a function parameter
#if X2017
            _toolsVersion = "15.0";
#endif
#if X2019
            _toolsVersion = "Current";
#endif

            var toolsPath = toolsets[_toolsVersion];
            _toolsPath = toolsPath; 
            
            // Use BuildParameters to load the settings which are defined in the MSBuild.exe.config and which would be loaded
            // if we specified ToolsetDefinitionLocations.ConfigurationFile as a ProjectCollection constructor parameter.
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBUILD_EXE_PATH", CombineFullPath(toolsPath, "MSBuild.exe"));
            var buildParameters = new BuildParameters();
            var toolset = buildParameters.GetToolset(_toolsVersion);
            var toolsetProperties = toolset.Properties;

            GlobalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var kvp in toolsetProperties)
            {
                if (kvp.Key != kvp.Value.Name)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                GlobalProperties.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.EvaluatedValue);
            }

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildExtensionsPath", GlobalProperties["MSBuildExtensionsPath"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildSDKsPath", GlobalProperties["MSBuildSDKsPath"]);

            // QED: pass the global variables to the ProjectCollection
            ProjectCollection = new ProjectCollection(GlobalProperties);

            foreach (var kvp in toolsets)
            {
                // this sets $(MSBuildToolsPath)
                ProjectCollection.AddToolset(new Toolset(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ProjectCollection, string.Empty));
            }
        }
```